# Read image from shape into userform image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking to read image from word shape and load it in userform image1 box
explain: its a word shape, and I fill it with picture rather than color
This not working, run-time error 9 object variable or with block variable not set
Word VBA

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisDocument.Shapes("Shape1").LinkFormat.SourceFullName)
```

Sample file
[enter link description here](https://files.fm/u/7mnkgxvh3)

Comment: And what is that `SourceFullName` property returning?

Comment: I have no idea, I just saw the code in the internet but not working

Comment: “Not working” isn’t an adequate decription of your problem. Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then use the [Edit link below your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71458752/edit) and add more detail to your question.

Comment: What value do you pass to the `LoadPicture` function? Did you try to run the code under the debugger?

Comment: Is there in the processed document a `Shape` named "Shape1" **linked to a file**? Do you understand my question?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.excelforum.com/word-programming-vba-macros/1373469-load-picture-from-shape-to-userform-image-content.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have word document, there is round shape named Shape1, its filled with picture, I have userform with img content, when userform load I want the image in Shape1 load into userform image content

Comment: You still have not provided enough information for anyone to be able to replicate your problem, let alone provide a solution. Where in the document is the shape that contains the image - main body? header? footer? Was the image inserted as a linked image, or saved with the document? Do you get any error messages? If so, what is the error description?

Comment: image in shape, using filling shape with image in body not header or footer, I add a sample file and u can see the run-time error 9 object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: The code in your question will only work with a ***linked image***. If the image has been saved with the document the only way to extract it requires closing the document, renaming and unzipping the docx file, copying the image from the media folder to another disk location, rezipping and renaming the docx file. None of this can be done if the code is running from the document.

Comment: Ok this for linked image, so what the correct code for my situation to read image from shape?